# ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework database-first for N-Tier programming

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is just a question on N tier programming with architecture setup.

My previous project I tried to do with N tier programming with ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework. After trying, I still couldn't move generated entity object classes (edmx) to another project (BusinessEntity). I am only able use it at the DataAccess layer and directly link to the presentation layer. And next project I am hoping to use more correct way to develop.

Does anyone know how to set up a common entity object at different project and use it as common object for all 3 layer using the database-first method?

[image]

Comment: Thanks marc_s for edditing the content for me.

Comment: In my mind I allways seperate my models into an dto model, an business model and an entity model (no need to do this in code for all cases). So the idea of an common object for those 3 different layers models could be something stupit. The only common propery I can imagine is the `Id` which every model must have. But even then a business models id could be null where as in an entity models id this would be strange. What is the advantage of this common entity? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: This common entity is the object class. example of classes of Person,Kids,House with property in it. the advantage of layering is the code is neater as such easier to debug and someone who maintain it will be easier.